# Manage a patched workspace in git without sharing the patches

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-cherry-pick

I use git with SVN and I have a commit that I don't want to be pushed via dcommit but I need to do my local development.

The way I do it right now is

```
git checkout git-svn -B master
git cherry-pick ????..work
git svn dcommit
git checkout -B work
git cherry-pick mypatch^0
```

In the work branch, the commit after the git-svn tag has a commit containing `mypatch` after that is the work I actually do for the change set.

What I was wondering is whether it is possible to specify `????` as the second commit after `git-svn` on the `work` branch.  That way I don't have to go through the log and find the revision myself.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1994463/how-to-cherry-pick-a-range-of-commits-and-merge-into-another-branch

Comment: close but they have a different use case from what I can tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the proper sequence.  I needed to tag the new patch branch so I can refer to it symbolically.

```
git checkout git-svn -B master
git rebase --onto git-svn current-work-base work
git svn dcommit
git checkout -B work
git cherry-pick mypatch^0
git tag -f current-work-base
```

The tag `current-work-base` must point to the patch that comes after `git-svn`

This solution can work in a Windows batch file as well no need for bash.  (just change `^` to `^^`)

Please note that when rebasing the work branch, the `current-work-base` tag needs to be updated again.